# How to handle validation errors in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

How to handle validation errors to string in vbscript?
I don't understand why if I type a letter my code doesn't return to the loop

```
Dim mark
Dim ask
mark = Chr(10) & "   " & Chr(149) & " "

Do

    ask = InputBox("Select:" & Chr(10) & mark & "1) First" & mark & "2) Second" & mark & "3) All" & Chr(10), "Select a option")
    If IsEmpty(ask) Then WScript.Quit  'Read if canceled
    If IsNumeric(ask) and CStr(CLng(ask)) = ask and ask => 1 and ask <= 3 Then Exit Do
    MsgBox "Choice a valid value", 48, "Ops..."
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of a character, your `If` statement will generate an error because you are converting `ask` (which is a String in this scenario) to a Long (`CLng(ask)`). You should check if `ask` is numeric and then, in another statement, check the value:

```
If IsNumeric(ask) Then
    If CStr(CLng(ask)) = ask And ask >= 1 And ask <= 3 Then Exit Do
End If
```